# Tailwind overlow-y-scroll clips overflow on the x axis

Tags: html

I have a side menu that once I hover on top of the Icons I would like the name for that link to overflow on the x axis. Since I have many Icons, I'm using overflow-y-scroll in Tailwind CSS. However, once I use it the overflowing text on the x axis is clipped. Can anyone help?